# Test_flask file not using test database to run unittests

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, flask

I'm trying to write and run unittests for a flask app that's using sqlalchemy and WTForms. The configuration on my test_flask.py file is as follows:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from app import app
from models import db, Pet

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///petagency_test'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = False
app.config['TESTING']=True
app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED']=False

db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
```

When I run the test, however, it uses my production database (postgresql:///petagency) rather than the test database I've referenced here. I've show the code to a few people and no one has been able to tell me what's going wrong.

As far as I can tell, at least the last config line IS being read, because my unittests do pass and the CSRF would have to be turned off for that to be true. But it seems to be ignoring both the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI config and the SQLALCHEMY_ECHO config.

I've shown it to a few people with more experience than me and their only recommendation was to add the `app.config['TESTING']=True` line which has not fixed the problem. Anyone have any ideas?

My app.py config is as follows if it is relevant:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, flash
from models import db, connect_db, Pet
from forms import AddPetForm, EditPetForm
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, BooleanField, TextAreaField
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from sqlalchemy import exc
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///petagency'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secret"
app.config['DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS'] = False

debug=DebugToolbarExtension(app)

app.app_context().push()

connect_db(app)
db.create_all()
```

db is defined as:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def connect_db(app):
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
```

Comment: How is `db` in `from models import db, Pet` defined in `models`?

Comment: I added that information to the original question at the bottom.

Comment: I'm going to say that is using the connection string from your  `app` in `app.py` and never sees the changes made in `test_flask.py`. `app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED']=False` works because it is not used in `app.py`.